# Why Python allows storing different objects in a list?

Tags: python, oop

I'm taking exam about python, and one of the listed questions in terms of OOP is:
"Can you store objects from different class in one list and why?"
So you can do that, but is there any specific purpose to do that?

Comment: The question might be interpreted as "name the reason why it is possible".

Comment: Polymorphic behavior? Policy-based design (e.g.: all classes in that list have certain methods)?

Comment: Would you rather store all `Shapes` in a the same list, or have a seperate list for `Circle`, `Triangle` and `Square`?

Comment: @DeepSpace In a traditional statically typed language like C++, your `Circle`, `Triangle`, and `Square` would be subclasses of `Shape`, and you can just create a list of type `Shape` and add all the subclass instances in there.

Comment: "Why" as in "Why is this possible?" or "Why did the creators decide to do it that way?"

Comment: I'm guessing that the question implies that there is a specific reason to do that. So not "why is that possible" but "why would you do that".

Comment: @DerekJohnson See my answer in that case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any specific purpose to do that?

Python is a [duck typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) language, so while objects might be of a different type, they can still *behave* similarly.

A common example of this is a list of callback functions; you don't actually know whether they're functions, or instances of some custom class that implements the `__call__` method:

```
my_event_callbacks = []
my_event_callbacks.append(my_callback)
...
for callback in my_event_callbacks:
    callback(my_event_data)
```

You can't tell, nor should you care, whether `my_callback` is just a simple function or a callable instance.